# How do you get the ImageSource or value from Background?

Tags: c#, uwp

I have a Canvas which has a set background using an ImageBrush and ImageSource in the XAML.

`<ImageBrush ImageSource="/Assets/mainDiagram.jpg" />`

I'm wondering how I can get the ImageSource or values from the Background member on the Canvas object.

Here is the code I'm working with:

```
// this is the resolution of the background source image
private int[] BkgResXY
{
    get
    {
         int[] bkgResXY = new int[2];

         bkgResXY[0] = (int)(double)this.Background.GetValue(Panel.MaxWidthProperty);
         bkgResXY[1] = (int)(double)this.Background.GetValue(Panel.MaxHeightProperty);

         return bkgResXY;
    }
}
```

EDIT:

I see there are multiple height properties on the Panel class, Background inherits from the Panel Class. Not sure which one would be the ImageSource resolution.

EDIT:

So I've gotten this far `(this.Background as ImageBrush).ImageSource` but I hit a road block because ImageSource doesn't contain the original height and width of the source image.

EDIT:

I did this to get the background image resolution:

```
bkgResXY[0] = ((this.Background as ImageBrush).ImageSource as BitmapSource).PixelWidth;
bkgResXY[1] = ((this.Background as ImageBrush).ImageSource as BitmapSource).PixelHeight
```

Comment: You should not use `as` without checking the result for null. In case the cast fails, you will get a NullReferenceException instead of the correct InvalidCastException. So if you don't want the null check, write `((BitmapImage)((ImageBrush)Background).ImageSource).PixelWidth`

Answer (score 2):

To access the properties of an `ImageBrush` you need to cast the `Background` property first. To be safe I would prefer the usage of the `as` operator instead of a simple cast. Having the `Canvas`

```
<Canvas x:Name="myCanvas">
    <Canvas.Background>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="1.jpg" />
    </Canvas.Background>
</Canvas>
```

you are able to get the original width of your background image like

```
var canvasBackground = myCanvas.Background as ImageBrush;
if (canvasBackground != null)
{
    //Get the ORIGINAL width of the source

    var bitmapImage = canvasBackground.ImageSource as BitmapImage;
    if (bitmapImage != null)
    {
        var originalBackgroundWidth = bitmapImage.PixelWidth;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you are using C# 6 you can combine the first two lines to `if (myCanvas.Background is ImageBrush canvasBackground)`

Comment: Is there a way I can access the height and width of the original image? Without like reloading it?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain That's only in C#7, not 6.

Comment: for me `ImageSource.Width;` doesn't exist

Comment: The property should devinitively exist: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imagesource.width(v=vs.110).aspx - At my example project the code runned perfectly.

Comment: Ah, I'm using `Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.media.imagesource